# Logical fallacy brain-freeze

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, logic, rhetoric

There must be a name for this sort of after-the-fact non-argument.
Sorry, this is the only way I could find to describe it.

---

Debbie finds a kitten.
Kitten has been burned over half its body, but it's alive.

Debbie says, 'The kitten wants to live!' and takes it to a vet.

Bob says, 'The kitten is suffering and will continue to suffer horribly, the kindest thing would be to euthanize her.'

Debbie refuses; the kitten continues to suffer for months but in the end manages to survive.

Bob says, 'The kitten suffered unnecessarily.'

Debbie then says to Bob, 'The kitten would now be dead had it been up to you. You have no respect for life.'

Comment: I see no logical fallacy here, just two people talking past each other: neither party addresses the premises of the other.

Comment: Please highlight what you consider a fallacy, you seem (though you have in no way made this clear) to be looking for a word that describes a concept. Please [edit] your question to i) make it a question and ii) explain what exactly you're looking for. As far as I can tell, neither Bob nor Debbie are applying any kind of logic.

Comment: Oy..I knew i would not be able to clearly explain what I'm trying to get at.
Possibly the incorrect place to ask?

Comment: Just explain which part of this you consider an " after-the-fact non-argument" and tell us if you are looking for a word for that, or a phrase, or an analysis of the logic.

Comment: Okay I'll try one more time and if i don't get it  across
adequately i'll delete the whole thing with apologies.

John's mother did not terminated her pregnancy.
Therefore abortion is wrong because John is alive.

Comment: I'm not even entirely clear whether you think Debbie or Bob is committing the fallacy.

Comment: Debbie, because she assumes that Bob is wrong because the outcome is positive.

Comment: Does this example fall into the category you are looking for? "- Shooting people is dangerous! - No it's not, I did it yesterday and nobody got hurt"?

Comment: Oi..my ex used that one regarding seat belts.
"I haven't had an accident in 20 years. Why should I use a seat belt'.
Please tell me there is a name for that one.

Comment: Debbie's implicit premise is that the possibility that the kitten will survive the suffering makes the effort to sustain its life obligatory. Bob's implicit premise is that actual suffering makes that effort intolerable. Neither addresses the other's premise.

Comment: And here's no premise at all: This is not about the English language.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, from your last comment, that you are thinking of "argument from consequences", also called "*argumentum ad consequentiam*".

Comment: +1 It's perhaps worth pointing out that this is not necessarily a fallacy, and that both parties to the debate adopt it.

Comment: @StoneyB it's a fallacy when it doesn't actually logically follow. I don't think the example is a clear case, as there is a difference between ethics of consequences and argumentum ad consequentiam, and it seems to me that the example are two people with an ethics of consequences, each valuing different consequences.

Comment: So 
Debbie's argument is, the end justifies any interim negative consequences.
Bob's argument is, negative interim consequences are NOT justification of the end, be the end positive  or negative.

Which makes this an ethical conundrum having nothing to do with logic?

Comment: @TerryWard yes, since unpleasant consequences actually do logically follow from either action, each position is logically consistent.

Comment: Y'all are amazing...

So this is where I stepped in it coming here..
I think.
 "Appeal to emotion  is a type of informal fallacy, since the desirability of a consequence does not make it true"

What I had in mind was finding a type of fallacy illustrating that the desirability of a consequence does not make it RIGHT.
So if my concern is what makes or does not make a premise right,- as opposed to 'true'- have I set my tent-posts in the wrong forum?

Comment: Your abortion example is a better one, because the consequence is less logically related (sure, I'd not be here if I wasn't aborted, but then my feelings about my not being here wouldn't be pertinent because I wouldn't be here). Likewise, "I drove without my seatbelt and I wasn't hurt" is better still, as my driving without my seatbelt did not help me not be hurt.

Comment: But we get into http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ territory with that.

Comment: Would you say then that the successful explanation of ethics
cannot be achieved without logic, but the application of logic is unconnected to ethics?
Or is this a logical fallacy implying that the two disciplines are 'equal'

Comment: I'd say that logic is part, but not all, of ethics, but that's definitely into philosophy.stackexcange.com territory!